# Insert query is not working in my php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am getting values from a csv file and inserting them into my sql tables.
I am trying to insert(or replace). It is not working. But when i use update query it works just fine and updates values correctly.
I am not sure what is wrong in my script.

```
$query_insert = "
INSERT INTO
    `ps_product`
    (
         `id_product`
        ,`id_supplier`
        ,`id_manufacturer`
        ,`id_category_default`
        ,`id_shop_default`
        ,`id_tax_rules_group`
        ,`on_sale`
        ,`online_only`
        ,`ean13`
        ,`upc`
        ,`ecotax`
        ,`quantity`
        ,`minimal_quantity`
        ,`price`
        ,`wholesale_price`
        ,`unity`
        ,`unit_price_ratio`
        ,`additional_shipping_cost`
        ,`reference`
        ,`supplier_reference`
        ,`location`
        ,`width`
        ,`height`
        ,`depth`
        ,`weight`
        ,`out_of_stock`
        ,`quantity_discount`
        ,`customizable`
        ,`uploadable_files`
        ,`text_fields`
        ,`active`
        ,`redirect_type`
        ,`id_product_redirected`
        ,`available_for_order`
        ,`available_date`
        ,`condition`
        ,`show_price`
        ,`indexed`
        ,`visibility`
        ,`cache_is_pack`
        ,`cache_has_attachments`
        ,`is_virtual`
        ,`cache_default_attribute`
        ,`date_add`
        ,`date_upd`
        ,`advanced_stock_management`
    )
    VALUES
    (
         " .$ID ."
        ,'2'
        ,'" .$id_manu ."'
        ,'" .$categoryRec ."'
        ,'2'
        ,'2'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'" .$EAN ."'
        ,'" .$UPC ."'
        ,'0.000000'
        ,'0'
        ,'1'
        ,'" .$retailp ."'
        ,'" .$wholesalep ."'
        ,''
        ,'0.000000'
        ,'0.00'
        ,'" .$ref ."'
        ,'" .$ID ."'
        ,''
        ,'0.000000'
        ,'0.000000'
        ,'0.000000'
        ,'0.000000'
        ,'2'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'1'
        ,''
        ,'0'
        ,'1'
        ,'0000-00-00'
        ,'new'
        ,'1'
        ,'1'
        ,'both'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'0'
        ,'" .$dateadded ."'
        ,'" .$dateupdated ."'
        ,'0'
    )
";

//  echo $query_insert;

mysql_query( $query_insert ,$conn );
```

But using the same values my update query works perfect. Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here??

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `ps_product` SET `id_supplier`=1,`id_manufacturer`=$id_manu,`id_category_default`=$categoryRec,`id_shop_default`=1,`id_tax_rules_group`=1,`on_sale`=0,`online_only`=0,`ean13`='$EAN',`upc`='$UPC',`ecotax`=0.000000,`quantity`=0,`minimal_quantity`=1,`price`='$retailp',`wholesale_price`='$wholesalep',`unity`='',`unit_price_ratio`=0.000000,`additional_shipping_cost`=0.00,`reference`='$ref',`supplier_reference`=$ID,`location`='',`width`=0.000000,`height`=0.000000,`depth`=0.000000,`weight`=0.000000,`out_of_stock`=2,`quantity_discount`=0,`customizable`=0,`uploadable_files`=0,`text_fields`=0,`active`=1,`redirect_type`='',`id_product_redirected`=0,`available_for_order`=1,`available_date`='0000-00-00',`condition`='new',`show_price`=1,`indexed`=1,`visibility`='both',`cache_is_pack`=0,`cache_has_attachments`=0,`is_virtual`=0,`cache_default_attribute`=0,`date_add`='$dateadded',`date_upd`='$dateupdated',`advanced_stock_management`=0  WHERE `id_product`=$ID",$conn);
```

I must mention that the product that i am entering is not in the table and the product that i am updating is in the system. So that i have already tested.

Comment: `mysql` interface is deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. This code looks vulnerable to SQL Injection. Potentially unsafe values included in the SQL text must be properly escaped. The better pattern is to use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**. (One syntax error in the INSERT statement is a missing backtick character.)

Comment: Sometimes when a SQL statement "is not working", it's due to the failure of query execution. When that happens, the SQL error message can usually be retrieved with a call to an interface library function, such as `mysql_error`. The code should check the return from the query execution, rather than putting its pinky finger to the corner of its mouth, Dr. Evil style, and saying "I just assume it will all go to plan. What?"

Comment: @spencer7593 this is the error i am getting. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'online_only`,`ean13`,`upc`,`ecotax`,`quantity`,`minimal_quantity`,`price`,`whole' at line 1 . When i check online_only the quote is correct it is the one that comes before 1 in keyboard, it is not the single quote so why would this error come up? voteup for error check and mysqli/pdo tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Online_only isn't quoted properly

Comment: Oh thanks for that i just changed that quote and tried again. It still is not inserting a value. I updated my question with the quote now.

Comment: I got it there was another closing quote missing on on_sale. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For primary key that is id_supplier you are providing a value as $ID instead give a empty value as follows

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ps_product` (`id_product`,`id_supplier`,`id_manufacturer`,`id_category_default`,`id_shop_default`,`id_tax_rules_group`,`on_sale,online_only`,`ean13`,`upc`,`ecotax`,`quantity`,`minimal_quantity`,`price`,`wholesale_price`,`unity`,`unit_price_ratio`,`additional_shipping_cost`,`reference`,`supplier_reference`,`location`,`width`,`height`,`depth`,`weight`,`out_of_stock`,`quantity_discount`,`customizable`,`uploadable_files`,`text_fields`,`active`,`redirect_type`,`id_product_redirected`,`available_for_order`,`available_date`,`condition`,`show_price`,`indexed`,`visibility`,`cache_is_pack`,`cache_has_attachments`,`is_virtual`,`cache_default_attribute`,`date_add`,`date_upd`,`advanced_stock_management`) VALUES ('',2,$id_manu,$categoryRec,2,2,0,0,'$EAN','$UPC',0.000000,0,1,'$retailp','$wholesalep','',0.000000,0.00,'$ref',$ID,'',0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,2,0,0,0,0,1,'',0,1,'0000-00-00','new',1,1,'both',0,0,0,0,'$dateadded','$dateupdated',0)",$conn);
```

As Primary key is an autoincrement it will increment automatically

Comment: That doesn't throw an error. Sometimes people fill gaps. Give it a try.

Comment: I have id_product as $ID and id_supplier is 2.

Comment: Generally speaking dont supply the id column. Let the db engine do it. If you try to create a dupe of an existing Value it fails